# Error while calling service from angular component opened in office.js dialog

Tags: javascript, angular, office-js, angular-services, angular-httpclient

My application is built on Angular 5 and we are using Office.js for interacting with MS office word document.

Step 1: Invoking office displayDialogAsync to load the component.
[image]

Step 2: Within the attribute-users component, I am invoking HTTPS GET to get all users based on the search term

[image]

Step 3: The angular service uses HttpClient (this.http) to call the service
[image]

However, the call errors out and prints this error message on browser console
[image]

**Note - If the attribute-users component is called via angular router (this.router.navigate) instead of loading it in office.js dialog, it works fine! Also, for above issue, the http call is also not seen in network traffic.**

Any thoughts on what am I missing here?

Answer (score 0):

(Deleted my original answer in light of the OP's clarification that he is using HTTPS.)

New answer:

1. When you open an Office Dialog, you are opening a completely different instance of the browser and its JavaScript runtime. When you pass a route from your Angular app to the dialog, you are launching a completely separate instance of your app in the dialog. I don't recommend this. I recommend that you create a simple HTML page to launch in the dialog, even though this technically means you don't literally have a "single page" app anymore. This page should do very little. Just get the access token and pass it back to the parent page, usually a task pane page, with the `messageParent` API. Everything meaty in the app should be happening in the parent page. This would include your getUsersFromIcmM and getIcm.
2. If you don't take my advice in #1, then here's a troubleshooting step you should take: Assign a handler to the DialogEventReceived event and see what error message you are getting. For details see [Errors and events in the dialog window](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/develop/dialog-api-in-office-add-ins#errors-and-events-in-the-dialog-window). (And, if you haven't already, read the whole of that article.)